# Validation Error Mongoose

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have been adding validations to my fields with Mongoose but when I test it, Mongoose says me that I not pass the max validation in the _id attribute

```
    var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema{
      _id : {
        type : number,
        min:[6,"Your id is too short"],
        max:[10,"Your id is too large"]
        //This is the validation that sends
        // me when I put 2013090464 (10 digits)
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

_id can't be `type: number`, it's an ObjectId.

> The type assigned is an ObjectId to coincide with MongoDB's default behavior.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#_id

And why don't you let mongo manage your _id ?